# New column in a table and problem with update function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem with my UPDATE functions and I need your help.

I created a table Computers(COM_ID,Company,Price,Model,Description,CAT_ID,Image,Quantity)

**I have a web service(AdminCentral.asmx) with this code**

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Updates a  computer in the computer table", EnableSession = false)]

public string updateItem(string comid, string company, double price, string model, string description, string image, int CAT_ID, int quantity)

{

    try

    {

        dbConn = new DbConnection();

        SqlConnection conn = dbConn.OpenConnection();

        SqlCommand updateItem = new SqlCommand("UpdateComputer", conn);

        updateItem.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


        SqlParameter updatecomid = updateItem.Parameters.Add("@COM_ID", SqlDbType.Char, 15);
        updatecomid.Value = comid;

        SqlParameter updateCompany = updateItem.Parameters.Add("@Company", SqlDbType.Char, 90);
        updateCompany.Value = company;

        SqlParameter updatePrice = updateItem.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.Money, 8);
        updatePrice.Value = price;

        SqlParameter updateModel = updateItem.Parameters.Add("@Model", SqlDbType.Char, 150);
        updateModel.Value = model;


        SqlParameter updateDescription = updateItem.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.Char, 255);
        updateDescription.Value = description;

        SqlParameter updateImage = updateItem.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.Char, 50);
        updateImage.Value = image;


        SqlParameter updateCatId = updateItem.Parameters.Add("@CAT_ID", SqlDbType.Int, 2);
        updateCatId.Value = CAT_ID;

        SqlParameter updateQuantity = updateItem.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Int, 2);
        updateQuantity.Value = quantity;

        return this.ExecuteQuery(updateItem);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return e.ToString();

    }
}
```

In a different application I created the web reference and I have this Datagrid

```
<asp:datagrid id="Computerchange" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderColor="Gainsboro" Height="500px"

                            <Columns>
                                <asp:EditCommandColumn ButtonType="LinkButton" UpdateText="Update" HeaderText="Admin Functions" CancelText="Cancel" EditText="Edit"></asp:EditCommandColumn>
                                <asp:ButtonColumn Text="Delete" HeaderText="Delete" CommandName="Delete"></asp:ButtonColumn>
                                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="com_id" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="Computer Number"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="company" HeaderText="Company"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="price" HeaderText="Price"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="model" HeaderText="Model"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="description" HeaderText="Description"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="id" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="Category"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="imgSrc" HeaderText="Image"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="quantity" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="Quantity"></asp:BoundColumn>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:datagrid>
```

**and I wrote this function**

```
private void Computerchange_UpdateCommand(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridCommandEventArgs e)

{

    //Store updated column values in local variables:
    string updateCOM_ID = e.Item.Cells[2].Text;
    string updateCompany = ((TextBox)e.Item.Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text;
    double updatePrice = double.Parse(((TextBox)e.Item.Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text);
    string updateModel = ((TextBox)e.Item.Cells[5].Controls[0]).Text;
    string updateDescription = ((TextBox)e.Item.Cells[6].Controls[0]).Text;
    int updateCategoryId = int.Parse(e.Item.Cells[7].Text);
    string updateImage = ((TextBox)e.Item.Cells[8].Controls[0]).Text;
    int updateQuantity = int.Parse(e.Item.Cells[9].Text);
    newView.RowFilter = "com_id='" + updateCOM_ID + "'";
    if (newView.Count > 0)
    {
        //Delete the row that is being updated
        newView.Delete(0);
    }
    newView.RowFilter = "";

    //Create a new DataRow and populate it with the new data.
    DataRow Row = Table.NewRow();
    Row["com_id"] = updateCOM_ID;
    Row["company"] = updateCompany;
    Row["price"] = updatePrice;
    Row["model"] = updateModel;
    Row["description"] = updateDescription;
    Row["id"] = updateCategoryId;
    Row["imgSrc"] = updateImage;
    Row["quantity"] = updateQuantity;

    //Insert the new DataRow:
    Table.Rows.Add(Row);
    Computerchange.EditItemIndex = -1;
    Computerchange.DataSource = newView;
    Computerchange.DataBind();

    // Now update the database with the new data
    adminCentral1.adminCentral newData = new adminCentral1.adminCentral();
    string results;
    results = newData.updateItem(updateCOM_ID, updateCompany, updatePrice, updateModel, updateDescription, updateImage, updateCategoryId, updateQuantity);

    if (results == "Success")
    {
        errorLabel.Text = "Computer Updated to database!";
    }
    else
    {
        errorLabel.Text = results;
    }
```

When I click the Update button the error which I have is

```
"**Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index**"

Stack Trace:

[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index]

   System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) +8750274
   AdminMainPage.Computerchange_UpdateCommand(Object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e) +626
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid.OnUpdateCommand(DataGridCommandEventArgs e) +115
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +498
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItem.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +121
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +125
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +169
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +9
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +176
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563
```

Can you please help me with this error? I would like to mention that first, I didn't have the Quantity column and the code was working. When I inserted the Quantity column then I had this error. I think that I am trying to access a control which is not created or not exist in the collection.

Comment: its difficult to read long question. Please post the relevant code only.

Comment: I wrote my question with details because if I delete something maybe the readers will not understand exactly what is going wrong with my code

Comment: You have exactly what the error is telling you: an array index is out of bounds. The only place you're using array indices is when you're pulling values from the cells in your Grid (e.g. `e.Item.Cells[5].Controls[0]`). Make sure that you don't have a null control each time you index into a control collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Specified argument was out of the range of valid values."Parameter name: index*` means you tried to access collection outside its range

The top two lines of stacktrace are

```
  System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) +8750274
   AdminMainPage.Computerchange_UpdateCommand(Object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e) +
```

This means in the method `Computerchange_UpdateCommand` you're accessing the Control Collection by an index that doesn't exist.

Unfortunatly you reference the control several times, any of the following could be the problem

```
string updateCOM_ID = e.Item.Cells[2].Text;
string updateCompany = ((TextBox)e.Item.Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text;
double updatePrice = double.Parse(((TextBox)e.Item.Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text);
string updateModel = ((TextBox)e.Item.Cells[5].Controls[0]).Text;
string updateDescription = ((TextBox)e.Item.Cells[6].Controls[0]).Text;
int updateCategoryId = int.Parse(e.Item.Cells[7].Text);
string updateImage = ((TextBox)e.Item.Cells[8].Controls[0]).Text;
int updateQuantity = int.Parse(e.Item.Cells[9].Text);
```

However this is the most likely candidate.

```
int updateQuantity = int.Parse(e.Item.Cells[9].Text);
```

I suggest you put a breakpoint on the first one and step through and see which one is failing.

Comment: Finally is Quantity. But unfortunately I dont know what can I do to fix it.

Comment: @theo1985  Is there a quantity column in the datasource? Does it appear on the ASP.NET page when you view it?

Comment: Yes there is. If you check above I have a BoundColumn for the quantity. Also I can Edit to this field. But when I try to update it then I have this error every time.

Comment: I found something. When I delete the ReadOnly from the Quantity Column then it works. But when I have it then I have this error. Do you know why?

Comment: @theo1985. I had considered that but you have other readonly fields. Maybe because its the last item in the collection? I didn't get a chance to further investigate.

Comment: I changed the position and again I have the same error with the readonly. Maybe I will ask a new question about that. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is a LOT of information to read through...  A few things you can do to narrow-down the scope a bit:

1) Make sure your index is not out of range.  Typically, indexes cannot be less than 0.
2) Step through your execution with debug.  While debugging, track the value of your index variable.
3) Run your stored procedure manually (via SSMS)

Answer (score 0):

The one useful piece of information I don't see is which line of code is actually throwing your exception.  Since the exception showed up after you added quantity I would suggest putting a break point on this line of code.

```
int updateQuantity = int.Parse(e.Item.Cells[9].Text);
```

When it hits the breakpoint step-over to see if this is the line throwing the exception.  If it is you know your Cells[9] doesn't actually exist and you have a clear idea of what needs to be fixed.

Comment: yes. Here it hits. In the quantity. Do you know what can I check now to fix it?